# My app looks different in Main.storyboard than in the simulator when using stack views

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I'm currently designing a layout of an app using the iPhone 11 Pro as the template and it looks like this in the storyboard:

[image]

But when I run it in an iPhone 11 Pro simulator, it looks like this:
[image]

All of my views are constrained and I'm using stackviews that are set to fill proportionally to format the boxes, but I don't know how to fix it while still retaining the same design that I want.

Comment: *"All of my views are constrained"* ... constrained how? *"fill proportionally"* ... is probably NOT what you want, but no way to know without further explanation of how you are setting constraints and what you expect as the result.

Comment: The purple boxes are in a stack view, and the stack view is pinned all around to the safe area. I want the end result to look like the first picture.

Comment: That's still ambiguous... Do you have a fixed (absolute) height for the Top view, and you want the other 5 views to fill the remaining space? Or do you have a fixed (absolute) height for each of the Bottom 5 views, and you want the Top view to fill the space? Or, do you maybe want the Bottom 5 views to all be equal heights, and the Top view to be 4x the height of one of the Bottom views?

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describing in detail (in plain language) what you want to get can be very helpful...

- Set your Stack View Distribution to `Fill`
- Constrain Bottom views 2, 3, 4 & 5 Equal Height to Bottom View 1
- Constrain Top view Height Equal to Bottom View 1 Height with Multiplier: 4.0

Result:

[image]